# How to save a new record when the id key is auto incremented

Tags: c#, ado.net, insert, auto-increment

I have created a database in sql server 2008 and a table with auto increment id field

Also I develop a project in c#.net 2008

The problem occurs on click "save data" after of "add new" from BindingNavigator

for example I click "add new", fill all fields except id text (blanked id) and then click 'save data' then occurs the errors

The runtime exception is "notNullAllowedException: the column 'id' not allowed null.

But it is not required from the user to fill this field but has to returned from database after the save

I also set the properties of the id: (both c# project and sql server)

```
AutoIncrement = True
AutoIncrementStep = -1 (also I tested 1)
AutoIncrementSeed = -1 (also I tested 1)
```

No results.

How I could handled that?

Thanks

Comment: If the ID column is set to identity, just pass `0` and not blank/`null`.

Comment: Another error when set 0 or -1  "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'mytable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Well, then switch it to 'on' :) If the Id column is `identity` and autoincrement with possibility to insert, then adding a new object with `Id` set to `0` should work just fine - the Id will get autoincremented.

Answer (score 4):

Don't include the identity column in your Insert statement.

If your statement is

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, SomeField, SomeOtherField) VALUES (null, 'SomeValue', 'AnotherValue')
```

simply change it to

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( SomeField, SomeOtherField) VALUES ( 'SomeValue', 'AnotherValue')
```

Comment: The problem is that c# auto-generate sql query for insert. I removed the id and worked! (of course I have to set -1 to id) the next time shows the normal id (or refreshing the recrod by code). But Microsoft didn't fixed that? thanks

Comment: I'm sure there's a workaround, but I'd need more specific info.  C# in and of itself doesn't do that.  Dynamic Data and several other technologies that are built on top of C# do...  Visual Studio does this when using the DataSet designer...  Linq to SQL ORM generation does it...  I guess there are so many possible ways to access data from C#, it's hard to tell you exactly how to work around this.  If you were to explain how you created your data access layer, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two problems.

First, you're always inserting - what logic do you use to decide whether 'save' should be an insert or an update? I think this is the case becuase of the errors you're getting: "Cannot insert explicit..."

Second, you need to get the ID that SQL assinged on your insert so you can write it to your ID field for the next save=update. There are a couple of ways to do this, the way I prefer is to use a stored procedure to do the insert and pass an OUTPUT parameter that gets SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Something like this:

```
CREATE PROC xyz
(
    @data...
    @NEWID INT OUTPUT
)
AS
    ... do your INSERT ...
    SET @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

)
```

double-check my syntax - not sure what version of SQL you're using

Comment: Thank you :) but I seek for a simple solution without procedure. c# auto-generate (ado.net) 3-4 sql queries (insert, update, delete etc) and calls the apropriate one automatically. The proble is auto-generated c# code add in sql insert the id without exist yet (insert into table set id=@id name=@name, ...) but this is wrong! I don't know why Microsoft miss out...